# PDO won't select database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having a really weird problem with PDO. It keeps telling me:

```
SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected
```

The code in question:

the settings.json file:

```
"connection" : {
    "handler" : "Meagl\\Core\\Connection\\SimplePdoMySql",
    "settings" : {
        "driver" : "mysql",
        "dsn" : "mysql:host=localhost;dbame=meagl",
        "username" : "meagl",
        "password" : "meagl"
    }
}
```

The SimplePdoMysql adapter constructor that creates the connection:

```
class SimplePdoMySql extends \Meagl\Core\Connection\SimplePdo {

    /**
     * Try and connect to the Database using PDO
     */
    public function __construct($config) {
        $this->connection = new \Pdo($config['dsn'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
        $this->connection->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
```

The function that is creating the error:

```
protected function selectAllResourceIdentifiers() {
    $sth = $this->connection->query("SHOW TABLES");
    return $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0);
}
```

If I check the errorInfo() on $this->connection I get the following array:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }
```

BEfore you ask, yes the $config array holds the correct values from the connection.json file

thx in advance for possible answers!

Comment: `dbame=meagl` - should that be `dbname=meagl`?

Comment: lol, I feel so stupid now :(. Note to myself: its best to stop programming after 8 hours :p

Comment: @andrewsi post an answer and ill give you the credits

Comment: I don't think there's anyone here who's not done exactly the same. (And I'm very reluctant to claim rep for spotting a typo - feel free to add an answer yourself and accept it when you can)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As andrewsi pointed out it was a really well placed typo